# Aggregating dataframe rows using groupby, combining multiple columns

Tags: python, group-by

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame(
    (
        (date(2023, 2, 27), timedelta(hours=0.5), "project A", "planning"),
        (date(2023, 2, 27), timedelta(hours=1), "project A", "planning"),
        (date(2023, 2, 27), timedelta(hours=1.5), "project A", "execution"),
        (date(2023, 2, 27), timedelta(hours=0.25), "project B", "planning"),
        (date(2023, 2, 28), timedelta(hours=3), "project A", "wrapup"),
        (date(2023, 2, 28), timedelta(hours=3), "project B", "execution"),
        (date(2023, 2, 28), timedelta(hours=2), "project B", "miscellaneous"),
    ),
    columns=("date", "duration", "project", "description"),
)
print(df)
>>>          date        duration    project    description
>>> 0  2023-02-27 0 days 00:30:00  project A       planning
>>> 1  2023-02-27 0 days 01:00:00  project A       planning
>>> 2  2023-02-27 0 days 01:30:00  project A      execution
>>> 3  2023-02-27 0 days 00:15:00  project B       planning
>>> 4  2023-02-28 0 days 03:00:00  project A         wrapup
>>> 5  2023-02-28 0 days 03:00:00  project B      execution
>>> 6  2023-02-28 0 days 02:00:00  project B  miscellaneous
```

I want to carry out aggregation for the `duration` and `description` columns, grouping by `date` and `project`. The result should look something like:

```py
result = pd.DataFrame(
    (
        (
            date(2023, 2, 27),
            "project A",
            timedelta(hours=3),
            "planning (1.5), execution (1.5)",
        ),
        (date(2023, 2, 27), "project B", timedelta(hours=0.25), "planning"),
        (date(2023, 2, 28), "project A", timedelta(hours=3), "wrapup"),
        (
            date(2023, 2, 28),
            "project B",
            timedelta(hours=5),
            "execution (3), miscellaneous (2)",
        ),
    ),
    columns=("date", "project", "duration", "description"),
)
print(result)
>>>          date    project        duration                       description
>>> 0  2023-02-27  project A 0 days 03:00:00   planning (1.5), execution (1.5)
>>> 1  2023-02-27  project B 0 days 00:15:00                          planning
>>> 2  2023-02-28  project A 0 days 03:00:00                            wrapup
>>> 3  2023-02-28  project B 0 days 05:00:00  execution (3), miscellaneous (2)
```

Aggregating the `duration` column is easy using `groupby()`:

```py
df.groupby(by=["date", "project"])["duration"].sum().to_frame().reset_index()
```

But I'm unsure how to handle the `description` column with `groupby()`. I considered using `DataFrameGroupBy.apply()` with custom functions on two levels, one for grouping by `date` and `project`, and one by `description`. Something like:

```py
def agg_description(df):
    ...
    
def agg_date_project(df):
  ...
  agg_description(...)
  ...

df.groupby(by=["date", "project"])["duration","description"].apply(agg_date_project)
```

But I can't figure it out. A complicating factor is that the aggregation for the `description` column is based on the `duration` column as well.
I could do it "manually" (e.g. using loops) but if possible I'd like to do it using `groupby()` as well.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `df.pivot_table(index=["date", "project"], values="duration", columns="description", aggfunc="sum")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in one go, without any use of `.apply`:

```py
result = (
    df.groupby(["date", "project", "description"], as_index=False).sum()
    .assign(description=lambda df:
        df["description"] + " ("
        + (df["duration"].dt.total_seconds() / 3_600).astype("str") + ")"
    )
    .groupby(["date", "project"], as_index=False).agg({
        "duration": "sum", "description": ", ".join
    })
)
```

- First calculate the sums for each `date`-`project`-`description` group.
- Then augment the `description` column with the resp. durations.
- Finally aggreate over `date`-`project` groups: summing for the `duration`s, and `", ".join`-ing for the `description`s.

Result:

```
         date    project        duration                           description
0  2023-02-27  project A 0 days 03:00:00       execution (1.5), planning (1.5)
1  2023-02-27  project B 0 days 00:15:00                       planning (0.25)
2  2023-02-28  project A 0 days 03:00:00                          wrapup (3.0)
3  2023-02-28  project B 0 days 05:00:00  execution (3.0), miscellaneous (2.0)
```

If you don't want that level of aggreation for the parts (in one column), then you could do:

```py
result = (
    df.pivot_table(
        values="duration", index=["date", "project"], columns="description",
        aggfunc="sum", fill_value=pd.Timedelta(0)
    )
    .assign(duration=lambda df: df.sum(axis=1))
    .reset_index()
)
```

Result:

```
description        date    project       execution   miscellaneous  \
0            2023-02-27  project A 0 days 01:30:00 0 days 00:00:00   
1            2023-02-27  project B 0 days 00:00:00 0 days 00:00:00   
2            2023-02-28  project A 0 days 00:00:00 0 days 00:00:00   
3            2023-02-28  project B 0 days 03:00:00 0 days 02:00:00   

description        planning          wrapup        duration  
0           0 days 01:30:00 0 days 00:00:00 0 days 03:00:00  
1           0 days 00:15:00 0 days 00:00:00 0 days 00:15:00  
2           0 days 00:00:00 0 days 03:00:00 0 days 03:00:00  
3           0 days 00:00:00 0 days 00:00:00 0 days 05:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! As I noted in my comment to @florent-monin's solution I need to keep the `description` column for a subsequent step but I can modify your solution.

Answer (score 2):

This one is a bit tricky, you will need a few intermediate steps:

First, let's compute the sum of the duration over each date, project and description:

```py
sum_df = df.groupby(by=["date", "project", "description"], as_index=False)["duration"].sum()
```

Then we need to get the duration in hours

```py
sum_df["duration_hours"] = sum_df["duration"].apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds()/60/60)
```

Now, we can format a string to contain the description, and time

```py
sum_df["description_time"] = sum_df.apply(lambda x: f"{x['description']} ({x['duration_hours']})", axis=1)
```

Then, we can aggregate by grouping by date and project only, to get the final description:

```py
sum_df["final_description"] = sum_df.groupby(["date", "project"])["description_time"].transform(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```

Finally, you will need to groupby again, and aggregate the duration to sum them, and keep final_description (I keep only the first, since all values are the same, across each group of the group by)

```py
sum_df.groupby(by=["date", "project"], as_index=False)[["duration", "final_description"]].agg({"duration": 'sum', "final_description": 'first'})
```

There you go!

(note that the formatting is not exactly the one you had in your expected result, since for the columns with only one type of description, there is still the time between parenthesis, but I believe it shouldn't be too hard to modify the result, if you really need to)

Comment: I think this is a good solution but a bit too complicated. Imho you don't need any `.apply`. Just override the `description` column: `sum_df["description"] = sum_df["description"] + " (" + (sum_df["duration"].dt.total_seconds() / 3_600).astype("str") + ")"`. And then skip the `.transform` step and directly do: `sum_df.groupby(["date", "project"], as_index=False).agg({"duration": "sum", "description": ", ".join})`?

Comment: Thanks both! As @Timus notes, the solution can be shortened. However, I need add a final step where I replace the description+hours string to just the description, for cases where there's only one description. For that step I need to keep the original `description` column.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to have every description's duration in a single column? Here is how I would do it:

```
# %%
df['planning'] = df[df['description'] == 'planning']['duration']
df['execution'] = df[df['description'] == 'execution']['duration']
df['wrapup'] = df[df['description'] == 'wrapup']['duration']
df['miscellaneous'] = df[df['description'] == 'miscellaneous']['duration']
df = df.fillna(timedelta(hours=0))
df
#%%
proj_duration = df.groupby(by=["date", "project"])["duration"].sum().to_frame().reset_index()
proj_duration
# %%
description_dration = df.groupby(by=["date", "project"])[['planning','execution','wrapup','miscellaneous']].sum().reset_index()
description_dration
# %%
final = proj_duration.merge(description_dration, on=['date','project'])
final
# %%
```

[Have a look to this image for the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeLoG.png)

If you have few descriptions it works well, otherwise you can create a list of descriptions, and work on that with loops.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @sonny-monti but that's not the result I was looking for. Even though I want to aggregate rows with the same description, the descriptions should not be seen as categories.